Cannot access dotenv variables from node module
I need to access dotenv variables from within a nested node module using process.env.[VARIABLE].
My file structure looks like this:
root
├── .env
└── server
    ├── server.js
    └── database
        ├── db.js
        └── models.js

inside server.js I load the env config at the beggining of import statements like this:
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });

console.log(process.env.DB_HOST) //This works as it should

import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import sequelize from './database/db.js'
import {User} from './database/models.js'


const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 5000;
// Middleware

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// Basic health check route
app.get('/api/health', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ status: 'Server is running' });
});


// Start the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});

If I log any of the variables i set up inside .env file from within server.js it works as it should. However if I try to log it from the db.js I get undefined value.
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
console.log(process.env.DB_HOST) ///returns undefined
console.log(process.env) ///returns the object containing env variables excluding the ones I set in my .env file

const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  dialect: 'mysql',
  port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306
});

export default sequelize;

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I tried changing the path to the .env file into an absolute one but that didn't help. I also experimented with positioning the dotenv.config before other imports as I found out this could be the reason but with no success.

"How do I use dotenv with import?"

Unrelated to your problem: You shouldn't use an .env file on the the server. Use environment variables. .env files are for development.

I am creating a web app that will be wrapped as a docker container later on. I am using .env file so that anyone who would like to set the app up on their device has the ability to change the main variables without the need to go through the code before building the image. If I decide to run the app publicly I'll get rid of the .env file

@jonrsharpe thanks for the link. Based on it when I changed the import statement to import 'dotenv/config' it works but it also means I had to change the location of .env file to be next to the server.js. I didn't find how to set up the path manually when importing the .env like this. Would you know?

Especially for Docker, you shouldn't use .env files. You can set environment variables when you build the image or change/set them when you run the container. Any type of credentials or configuration in files in Docker images is discouraged, because the layers are like a history. You can't never remove them, even when you delete the file, it's still in a hidden layer.

I don't see the difference between setting the env variables directly in docker-compose  or setting them in .env file from which it is then grabbed into docker-compose by ${ENV_VAR}? Am I missing something?

One difference is that you dotenv to read the file while Node.js can environment variables without third-party packages. Another difference is that you need an additional file instead key/value pairs that are written into environment variables. Files are stored on disk and environment variables are stored on memory. There are many differences. You write environment variables into a file and use a package to set the environment variables from the file. In Kubernetes, this becomes difficult.

And now, you have to fix a problem that wouldn't be there without .env file. You provided the best reason why you should avoid it.

The thing is it seemed to me as a good way to avoid human error when setting up the docker images to be built up. Say I have a db image and the nodejs server inside docker compose to create my container. Now you have to set 2 env variables for each separately even though they have the same values (prone to error).  Or you can use a variable that can be inline or inside .env and If I'm not wrong you do not need any external packages for compose to read them and will be passed as env vars to node. Sure dotenv is only for dev, I am currently still there

I'm only telling you this because it seems like it's still a relatively small and new project. Usually you will need different environments for dev, test, staging and prod, in the CI, on the local system and in the Kubernetes cluster. Tools like Portainer don't support .env files or at least I don't know how. The common solution for all these problems is to use .env files only for dev on the local system, and every else you use environment variables. They allow permissions. The product owner can see and change them in Gitlab CI. The devs don't need this permission.

sure is, never encountered the problem with importing env files I had (I wasnt using ES6 before) Thanks for the info. I'm not trying to argue, just trying to get to the bottom of it. Seems like I understand what you mean now:)

The explanation and at least one solution can be found in the first comment. Another solution (IMO without real explanation) can be found in the answer.

Imports are hoisted (see mozilla import Reference)
This means that regardless of where you place your import statements, they will always be executed before any other code in the file.
And because you exported a direct connection code to the database in ./database/db.js it runs before the .env file is loaded.
To avoid this, you can wrap your database connection logic inside a function. This ensures that the connection does not start immediately after import.
Example ./database/db.js:
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

export function connect() {  
  const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DB_NAME, process.env.DB_USER, process.env.DB_PASSWORD, {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'mysql',
    port: process.env.DB_PORT || 3306
  });
  return sequelize;
}

Example server.js:
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

import express from 'express'
import cors from 'cors'
import sequelize from './database/db.js'
import {User} from './database/models.js'


dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });

sequelize.connect()


Can you elaborate on the first paragraph? A reference would be even better. I'm sure, many users want to know why the import evaluated before the configuration.
